# Could marrying a career woman help you escape alimony?

Tags: family-law, divorce

Is it generally accepted that if a woman has access to a profession that she can support herself with that you could use this fact to escape alimony? I believe this to be so but is it in fact true. I see by some accounts you have the option to do a 'request for a vocational evaluation'. Does this mean if she can support herself she is expected to do so?

Comment: Worth noting, as always, that the law is not uniform across all jurisdictions. In Japan, for example, it doesn't matter because Japan doesn't have alimony that extends past the end of divorce proceedings (which are themselves quicker the most U.S. divorce cases in terms of time spent in litigation). In Saudi Arabia you look to Islamic law. Different U.S. states vary significantly in their alimony rules. I have no idea what the rules are, e.g., in Germany or Peru. Also, hard to tell what fact patterns are implicated. Relative wealth and income can matter. in some places, marital fault matters.

Comment: I did a rollback on an edit to this question, reverting an edit that asked the OP a question.  I was under the impression that this was bad practice, but if it's allowable, please feel free to un-revert it.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It is a bad practice, that is what comments are for.

Answer (score 2):

"Access to a profession"? It sounds like you're asking about someone who has educational credentials or past work experience but who is not currently working in a profession. Nowadays, in the USA, alimony awards are rare. And when it IS awarded, it is usually temporary (like a year or a few years) in order to help with the transition. If one spouse is not currently working and has not worked for several years in their previous profession, then they will most likely be rated at the capability of earning minimum wage.

Each state is different. Best to enquire directly with a local divorce attorney for your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Alimony is in principle not paid from man to woman (and nowadays things would be more complicated than that anyway), but from the wealthier to the less wealthy person. Both wealth and income would be taken into account.

If you are a multi-millionaire then just because your ex-wife can support herself, that will not stop alimony. If you are both multi-millionaires, neither will have to pay. If you are a pauper and she makes enough money to support you both, she'll have to pay. (All except that you never know what happens in court).

Comment: A good example might be if one spouse is making around 100k and the other is making multimillions the later would still be required to provide support even though the former could support themselves.

Comment: It's not clear that any of this is actually an accurate statement of the law, as opposed to a guess based on what happens in movies.

Comment: @NeilMeyer You do now it is possible for marriage to happen where the woman makes more then the man and would have to pay alimony right? Also from what I can see only one on the top 10 list appears to have gotten it from a divorce and most of the others in the top inherited it or earned it themselves. https://www.businessinsider.in/meet-the-top-10-richest-women-in-the-world/articleshow/68318378.cms

Comment: bdb484 Which law? No country was mentioned, so just trying to explain the general principles.

Comment: @JoeW The big amounts from the divorces referenced universally come from marital property division rules and not alimony rules.

Comment: @ohwilleke And what does that have to do with some of the richest women in the world getting it from inheritance or from earning it on their own? Everything I see suggests that most on that list didn't get it through divorce.

Comment: @JoeW It suggests that it is irrelevant to alimony rules, even in case in which it is divorce related (if any), which is the subject to the OP.

Comment: @ohwilleke It looks like the comment I was referring back to got deleted and it was making a claim that a lot of the richest women in the world got it from divorce.

Comment: @JoeW OK. I must have missed that comment and misunderstood what you were trying to say.

Comment: Are you claiming this is the actual law? Of what state or country? Or are you just saying that you think this is how it ought to be? There are lots of rules that I think would be good and fair, but that are not actually the law.

Comment: In which country? In many country alimony is only provided when someone sacrifices wealth/employment opportunities for the relationships (i.e. a stay-at-home parent). In many countries you can have a billionaire marrying a random person and still now have any alimony during the divorce. In some countries marriage doesn't even imply shared wealth, you may be able to choose to share and co-own everything or simply keep separate ownerships

Comment: @Jay Read all the comments before asking something already addressed. “Which law? No country was mentioned, so just trying to explain the general principles.”

Comment: @suchiuomizu That didn't answer the question. The general principles of ... what jurisdiction? If the poster is trying to assert that this is the general principle of most countries in the world, he could at least say that, and maybe give some source. Not asking for a well-documented scholarly paper here, but at least some assertion that this is based on actual law and not just how the poster thinks it ought to be.

Answer (score 1):

The laws are different in different countries, and in the US are different from state to state.

I was divorced in Ohio in 1997. In that place at that time, they had a formula for determining child support. (Child support, not alimony, but I'm getting there.) The formula was complicated but basically it said that they calculated an amount of support the child needed, and then the amount the custodial parent received was based on the other parent's share of their combined income. Like if they said the child needs, whatever, say $5,000 per year, and the husband makes $100,000 a year and wife makes $50,000 and the wife is the custodial parent, then the husband's share of the combined income is 2/3 and so he has to pay 2/3 of that $5,000 or $3,333.

At that time alimony was being phased out in Ohio so most divorce cases didn't involve alimony. When they did, the amount was entirely at the discretion of the judge. There was a list of factors the judge was supposed to consider, which included relative income of the two parties, but there was no formula or hard rules. Just, "The judge should consider the following factors ..."

On the other hand, I read at the time that in Texas the rule was that the non-custodial parent had to give the custodial parent a percentage of his income based on how many children they had. How much money the other person made was irrelevant. Personally I thought that was a better rule. A person couldn't get a "better deal" by deliberately quitting her job or otherwise sabotaging herself. What he had to pay was solely dependent on his income, what he did, and not on anything she did. But that's just my opinion.

So I think the short answer to your question is the ever-popular: It depends. It depends on the laws where you live. It often depends on the judge.

Oh, and by the way, I once read the suggestion that if you're planning to divorce your spouse, you should move to a place where the divorce laws most favor you, and live there long enough to qualify as a legal resident for divorce purposes before filing.

By the way #2: Choosing a spouse on the basis of who will result in you having the most favorable divorce settlement when you break up is probably not a productive idea. Certainly not very romantic.